# How to make fixed filenames for nuxt build in production?

Tags: docker, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt with SSR inside a Docker container. Whenever I build my project for production, it generates some random names for `js` file chunks. This causes some issues because of the browser's cache, which tries to load not existing js files. Because these files no longer exist, I am getting a lot of `not found` errors for js files built in the previous deployment.

How to can I deal with this problem?

Comment: At the end, the different filenames are used to avoid cache issues on production: if the name is the same, it may not take into account an update when you push your code. Here, a different Docker configuration is probably the best available fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something wrong with your browser caching policy and it's not working as expected because the not found/404 status code issue is not a common thing.

In order to answer your question about the fixed chunk name for production build in Nuxt, there is a built-in method to make it work and you can learn that by following the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#filenames).

So to achieve this you do this in the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    filenames: {
      chunk: () => '[name].js'
    }
  }
}
```

> Be careful when using non-hashed based filenames in production as most browsers will cache the asset and not detect the changes on first load.